# MySql query not working with having max clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I wonder why this query is not working. This is the query builder statement:

```
$this->getBuilder()
    ->select('code', 'name', 'date')
    ->groupBy('name', 'code')
    ->having('MAX(date)')
    ->get()
```

Which causes this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "?": syntax error (SQL: select "code", "name", "date" from "rival_rates" group by "name", "code" having "MAX(date)"  ) (Illuminate\Database\QueryException)
```

I don't know where is the question mark, there isn't any parameter.

If i run the sql query via mysql command line it works:

```
mysql> select code, name, date from rival_rates group by name, code having MAX(date);
+------+------+------------+
| code | name | date       |
+------+------+------------+
| 100  | tal  | 2014-10-01 |
| 100  | tal2 | 2014-10-05 |
| 200  | tal2 | 2014-10-03 |
+------+------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If i remove the 'having' part it's working. What is wrong with that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `select code, name, MAX(date) from rival_rates group by name, code ` Don`t know laravel but this should be your query

Comment: @Mihai I'm not arguing about the query itself. In my answer there is a way to execute such query, without discussing whether it makes sense or not.

Comment: You think that the query is wrong? I need the latest rates for every product code and for each of the different rivals rates, and the dates are not updated at the same time, so dates may be different. If there is a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `havingRaw`:

```
$this->getBuilder()
    ->select('code', 'name', 'date')
    ->groupBy('name', 'code')
    ->havingRaw('MAX(date)')
    ->get()
```

Comment: Of course, you couldn't do what OP needs otherwise. `having` is not capable of something like this.

Comment: What will be the query output?

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue in the syntax.

```
$this->getBuilder()
     ->select('code', 'name', 'date')
     ->groupBy('name', 'code')
     ->having('MAX(date)')
     ->get()
```

Here, having clause needs 3 arguments like `->having('MAX(date)', '>=', '2014-09-25')`

Note: First argument is for the column name, second for comparison operator and third is the comparing value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$condition = 'MAX(date)';

$this->getBuilder()
    ->select('code', 'name', 'date')
    ->groupBy('name', 'code')
    ->having($condition)
    ->get()
```

This will also work. If you don't want to give parameter to having clause.